# How to Close a Gtk# Window Programmatically?

Tags: gtk#

I am trying to close a Gtk# `Window` in the code by clicking a button. That is, the button should have the same effect as the `X` button in the title bar.

While the window does close, however, the `DeleteEvent` does not fire when clicking my own button, as opposed to clicking the `X` title bar button.

This is some minimal sample code:

```
    using System;

    using Gtk;

    namespace GtkSharpTest
    {
        class Program
        {
            [STAThread]
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Application.Init();

                using (Window win = new Window("Test")) {
                    win.SetSizeRequest(300, 200);
                    win.Hidden += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                        Application.Quit();
                    };
                    win.DeleteEvent += delegate(object o, DeleteEventArgs e) {
                        using (MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog(win,
                                                                     DialogFlags.Modal,
                                                                     MessageType.Question,
                                                                     ButtonsType.YesNo,
                                                                     "Really close?")) {
                            ResponseType result = (ResponseType)dlg.Run();
                            dlg.Destroy();
                            if (result == ResponseType.No) {
                                e.RetVal = true;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    Button bClose = Button.NewWithLabel("Close");
                    bClose.Clicked += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                        // ???
                    };
                    win.Add(bClose);

                    win.ShowAll();
                    Application.Run();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The line that I'm looking for is marked with `// ???`.

I have tried various calls there:

- `win.Hide();`
- `win.HideAll();`
- `win.Destroy();`

Both `Hide` and `Destroy` were suggested in [this forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=722111) for closing Gtk windows. [The selected answer in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005612/programmically-close-gtk-window) suggests `Destroy`, too, and even claims that the `delete` event gets fired when calling that method. However, I cannot reproduce that claim; all the aforementioned methods just make the window disappear, but the `DeleteEvent` is only ever fired if I close the window with the `X` title bar button.

In other words, you could say I am looking for a Gtk# equivalent of the Windows Forms/WPF `Close()` methods. Calling these exactly simulates a click on the `X` title bar button, as the respective `Closing` events are fired and there is still a chance to prevent the form/window from being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the delete event is only fired when the window manager tries to close the window (i.e. the user clicks on the X button.)

You can use `Destroy` to close a window. I'm not 100% sure but I think this triggers the `DestroyEvent`.

However, if you want to exactly simulate clicking the X button, then you need to send a `DeleteEvent` with `window.Event()`.

Comment: There is no `Event()` method available for the window, but after a while of browsing the docs, I suppose calling `ProcessEvent(Gdk.EventHelper.New(Gdk.EventType.Delete))` is the way to go. That seems to fire the `DeleteEvent`, but the window is not closed in response to that event - I still have to invoke `win.Destroy();` or `win.Hide();` myself if `ProcessEvent` returns `false`. Is this correct?

Comment: You're right, it looks like the [`gtk_widget_event()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-event) method has no equivalent in C#.

Comment: But the default handler for the DeleteEvent should close the window.

Comment: Seeing that the documentation text of [`gtk_widget_event()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-event) is almost exactly the same as that of [`Widget.ProcessEvent()`](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aGtk.Widget.ProcessEvent(Gdk.Event)), I am sure now that the latter is indeed the Gtk# equivalent for the former.

Comment: When testing, it seems to me like there is no default handler for the `DeleteEvent` in Gtk#. The only effect that emitting the event seems to have is that the `DeleteEvent` event is fired, and the return value of `ProcessEvent` is set according to what was written into `RetVal` in the event handlers registered with `DeleteEvent`.

Comment: The [C documentation for `delete-event`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-delete-event) says: "The default handler for this signal destroys the window." If GTK# doesn't do that, then that's a bug. But I suspect that GTK# _does_ have a default handler: what happens if you create an empty window, show it, run the GTK main loop, then close the window? The window disappears, doesn't it?

Comment: In an (almost) empty window, the `X` button closes the window, but a button that invokes `ProcessEvent(Gdk.EventHelper.New(Gdk.EventType.Delete));` doesn't do anything. Nothing visible at least - once I add some event handlers to the window's `DeleteEvent`, I can see that that event is fired upon clicking the button, but in any case the window stays there.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you have to emit the `DeleteEvent` _signal_ after all, instead of the `Delete` _event_. Let me know how that works.

Comment: I've tried `GLib.Signal.Emit(win, "delete-event");` now, but with that, the `DeleteEvent` isn't fired any more; I'm just getting the assertions `(:6748): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_set_boolean: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_BOOLEAN (value)' failed` (twice) and `(:6748): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_unset: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed` (once). I can find many websites referring to these assertions, but I have yet to find one that explains what exactly to change in my call to `Signal.Emit` in order to avoid them.

Comment: You have to provide the Gdk event as a third parameter to the signal emit call.

Comment: As in `GLib.Signal.Emit(win, "delete-event", Gdk.EventHelper.New(Gdk.EventType.Delete));`? This doesn't change anything; still getting said assertions :-/

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with the GTK# bindings, I only know C and Python. The C version, `g_signal_emit_by_name()`, needs to provide the widget, the string `"delete-event"`, a `GdkEvent`, and a location for the return value of the signal handler, which in this case is a Boolean so I think that's where that assertion failure is coming from. The Python version is actually a method on the `win` object, so maybe you're calling the wrong function?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be another suitable method; but also, there is no documentation on `GLib.Signal.Emit`, so I cannot really tell what it is supposed to do. I have figured `GLib.Signal.Emit` may be the suitable method based on [this forum discussion](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/gtk-sharp-list/2010-February/010105.html). As the `ProcessEvent` way was most promising so far, despite the fact that I have to manually invoke `Hide()` or `Destroy()` based on the return value of `ProcessEvent`, I'll go with that and thank you for all the input and insights into Gtk you have provided :-)

Comment: You could try looking at the GTK# source code to see what actual GTK API methods are called when you try each of those solutions. Good luck.